# Git commit signatures from people other than committer

Tags: git, github, gitlab

It looks like by default Git supports commit/tag signing only from the committer/tagger.  This largely makes sense; they are the one who has the rest of the object to sign.  However, it would be nice to get signatures from other people associated with a commit or tag:

- The author
- People who add a `Signed-off-by` or `Co-authored-by` trailer
- Code reviewers
- Testers
- The committer/author/etc. of earlier commit objects, in the case of a rebase or cherry-pick.

I can think of a few ways to do these, although the last one would be hard because the actual tree changes.  Other people have too; [here](https://gist.github.com/lrvick/d4b87c600cc074dfcd00a01ee6275420) is a design document for a third-party tool which links to previous tools that do it.

However, my question is if *Git itself* or any of the common Git hosting sites like GitHub or GitLab support any of these schemes directly.  Git signatures are already hard for people to first set up and use, and if they require more third-party tools to sign or verify then even fewer people would check them.

Comment: Git itself cannot do that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46936675/7976758 . PS. Neither close vote nor downvote are mine.

Comment: Yeah, I thought Git itself was least likely to be able to do it, because if it were I would have been able to find it in some of the man pages, but maybe something had changed and was poorly documented.  But that doesnʼt stop there from being a _de facto_ standard Iʼd missed; Git doesnʼt do anything with `Co-authored-by` trailers AFAIK but GitHub and GitLab both do.  (And I donʼt mind a downvote or close vote if my question is bad/unclear; I just wish I knew how to improve it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61489516/7976758 , https://github.com/mgorny/articles/blob/master/attack-on-git-signature-verification.rst

Comment: There are ways that Git could still get first-party support, or check multiple signatures properly instead of only checking the first like I think it does now, but “it seems reasonable to just reject them at the moment.” isnʼt promising that theyʼll do that any time soon.  GitHub, GitLab, or other sites might, using some notes-based scheme like `sig`, but if they do I havenʼt seen any indication of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is in theory possible to do this.  OpenPGP allows multiple signatures from different parties over the same data, and such data can be embedded in the signature field as a single ASCII-armoured blob.  I'm unsure if this is allowed for CMS (X.509) signatures or OpenSSH signatures, though.

However, as a practical matter, no tooling supports this at the moment.  You can certainly embed such signatures in a commit, but you have to do it yourself (e.g., by synthesizing the commit and using `git hash-object`)..  Git won't write such a thing when it signs a commit and I don't think GitHub or GitLab will verify them, although it's possible that if the committer signature is first, that they'll verify that signature and ignore the rest, but I haven't checked.  I *do* believe, however, that Git will correctly verify them, since Git farms out to GnuPG, and I believe GnuPG will handle this just fine.

Comment: As [linked in the question comments](https://github.com/mgorny/articles/blob/master/attack-on-git-signature-verification.rst), Git does not support multiple signatures in the standard format either; I think the current solution is to only verify the first, but I could be wrong and it shows an error every time.